# Awaiting Promise.all in jest test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

In `Comp` component, I have a `Promise.all` that runs when the component is rendered. I'm trying to test that `OnItemsUpdate()` is getting called once the `Promise.all` has resolved.

```
const Comp = ({OnItemsUpdate}) => {
    Promise.all(items.map((item) => {
        return datasource.UpdateItem(item);
    })).then(() => {
        return OnItemsUpdate();
    });

    // not including rest of the component for brevity's sake
}

it("Calls OnItemsUpdate when promises resolve", async () => {
    const props = {
        OnItemsUpdate: jest.fn();
    }

    expect(props.OnItemsUpdate).tohavebeencalledtimes(0);

    const control = mount(<Comp {...props} />);
    await datasource.UpdateItem

    expect(props.OnItemsUpdate).tohavebeencalledtimes(1); // doesn't get called

})
```

Awaiting `OnItemsUpdate` isn't working as `expect(props.OnItemsUpdate).tohavebeencalledtimes(1)` still returns 0.

Comment: if `datasource.UpdateItem(item)` returns a promise you need to add a `return` before it to wait for it to complete. also before `OnItemsUpdate();`

Comment: @AZ_ Both those functions are promises. I've added return before both but `props.OnItemsUpdate` still isnt being called

Comment: Slight change to the code: I actually want to await till the last `datasource.UpdateItem` gets resolved

Comment: Ok I've figured it out. It works if you `await datasource.UpdateItem` the same number of times as the items array length. Is there a more elegant of handling this?

Comment: you don't need async-await here, just return all promises correctly, you still are not returning Promise.all. `return Promise.all(....)`

Comment: once you mock all you calls(so they are already resolved) you may skip any numbers of microtasks(`Promise`) with single macrotask(`setTimeout(() => {your-checks-here}, 0)`)

Comment: @AZ_ better not rely on implementation details. it's not only about relying on `return` for `Promise.all`. Say to check if clicking button renders some data loaded we will not be able to `await` on internal method anymore(even if it returns `Promise`)

Answer (score 3):

You can fix this by using something like `setImmediate` to delay your assertions until after the callbacks in PromiseJobs have a chance to run.

`index.ts`:

```
import React from 'react';

export const Comp = ({ OnItemsUpdate, items, datasource }) => {
  Promise.all(
    items.map(item => {
      return datasource.UpdateItem(item);
    })
  ).then(() => {
    return OnItemsUpdate();
  });

  // not including rest of the component for brevity's sake
  return <div>test</div>;
};
```

Unit test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Comp } from './';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

describe('Comp', () => {
  it('t1', done => {
    const props = {
      OnItemsUpdate: jest.fn(),
      items: [1, 2],
      datasource: {
        UpdateItem: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('whatever')
      }
    };
    expect(props.OnItemsUpdate).toBeCalledTimes(0);
    const wrapper = mount(<Comp {...props}></Comp>);
    expect(props.datasource.UpdateItem).toBeCalledTimes(props.items.length);
    expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
    setImmediate(() => {
      expect(props.OnItemsUpdate).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57248527/index.spec.tsx
  Comp
    ✓ t1 (63ms)

 › 1 snapshot written.
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Snapshot Summary
 › 1 snapshot written from 1 test suite.

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   1 written, 1 total
Time:        5.322s
```

Snapshot:

```
// Jest Snapshot v1

exports[`Comp t1 1`] = `"<div>test</div>"`;
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57248527